# Rails search through `has_many :through` text fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mysql2

Let say I have a two models with association `has_many :through` between them.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_recipes
  has_many :categories, through: :category_recipes

  validates :name, presence: true

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_recipes
  has_many :categories, through: :category_recipes

  validates :title, presence: true
```

I want to create search functionality using ActiveRecord for mySQL database, which allow users to implement text search on `Recipe` title and Category `name`.

Now I have just:

```
@recipes = Recipe.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%")
```

How can I modify this query to search through both title of recipe and it's category names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Recipe.includes(:categories).where('recipes.title LIKE :query or categories.name like :query', query: "%#{params[:query]}%").references(:categories)
```

See: [Specifying Conditions on Eager Loaded Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it's not worked. Can't find a column `categories.name`

Comment: I just updated the answer.  I forgot to add `.references(:categories)`.  It should definitely work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. btw, can you give me a hint? I want to learn sql more precisely, is there any sql problem book? Book with exercises?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) to the associated table and query the name on either table with `OR`:

```
Recipe.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN category_recipes ON category_recipes.recipe_id = recipes.id")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN categories ON categories.id = category_recipes.id")
  .where("recipes.title LIKE :q OR categories.name LIKE :q", q: "%#{params[:query]}%").uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey try in this way**

```
@recipes = Recipe.includes(:categories).where('title LIKE ? or categories.name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%","%#{params[:query]}%")
```